# AS3: Accesing function on the maintime line from a extended movieclip class

Tags: actionscript-3, class

I have some movieclips on my main timeline with a class to extend these movieclips

ClickableMovieClip.as:

```
package {
    import flash.display.MovieClip;
    import flash.events.*;
    public class ClickableMovieClip extends MovieClip {
        public function ClickableMovieClip():void {
            this.buttonMode = true;
            this.addEventListener(MouseEvent.MOUSE_UP, onReleaseHandler);
        }
        public function onReleaseHandler(myEvent:MouseEvent) {
            //trace(" > "+this.name);
            testing();
        }
    }
}
```

And on my maintime line I have this function testing();

```
function testing(){
     trace("hello world!");
}
```

But the I can't 'reach' the testing function. I get this error:
"1061: Call to a possibly undefined method testing through a reference with static type flash.display:DisplayObjectContainer."

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 1):

First of all, how are you connecting your AS3 class to the stage? Importing it in a frame or using it as the Document Class?

This may have to do with inheritance.

Second, you may need to call it using `(root As MovieClip).testing()` or something like that. The idea is that you need to call it as a method of the stage or root. I don't remember exactly how it works.

**EDIT:**

As you said `MovieClip(parent).testing();` is the answer. I forgot the exact syntax before...

Comment: Thanks for pointing me in the right direction!
MovieClip(parent).testing(); was the trick for me

Comment: If that fixed your problem then you should mark the answer as correct. Just a thought.